# How to get stack trace of a running process from within a Visual Studio add-in?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in, stack-trace

I am writing a Visual Studio add-in in C# which will run while I am debugging a process in the same Visual Studio window and I need access to that the process' stack trace from within my add-in.  I tried putting this code into my add-in but it returns the add-in's stack trace, not the process I am debugging.

```
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace stacktrace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true);
System.Diagnostics.StackFrame stackframe = stacktrace.GetFrame(0);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to ask the debugger for the stack frames through the `DTE` automation object.  The `DTE` object should be available to you through your add-in.  The property you want is [`Debugger.CurrentThread.StackFrames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.thread.stackframes.aspx).  If you're using .NET 4, you can do:

```
    static string GetCurrentStackTrace(DTE dte)
    {
        bool canGetStackTrace =
            (dte != null) &&
            (dte.Debugger != null) &&
            (dte.Debugger.CurrentThread != null) &&
            (dte.Debugger.CurrentThread.StackFrames != null);

        if (!canGetStackTrace)
            return string.Empty;

        return string.Join(
            "\n",
            dte.Debugger.CurrentThread.StackFrames.Cast<StackFrame>().Select(f => f.FunctionName)
        );
    }
```

Otherwise, you can do:

```
    static string GetCurrentStackTrace(DTE dte)
    {
        bool canGetStackTrace =
            (dte != null) &&
            (dte.Debugger != null) &&
            (dte.Debugger.CurrentThread != null) &&
            (dte.Debugger.CurrentThread.StackFrames != null);

        if (!canGetStackTrace)
            return string.Empty;

        StringBuilder stackTrace = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (StackFrame frame in dte.Debugger.CurrentThread.StackFrames)
        {
            stackTrace.AppendFormat("{0}\n", frame.FunctionName);
        }

        return stackTrace.ToString();
    }
```

The painful and involved way would be to use [`ICorDebug`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230588.aspx) and [`StackWalk64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680650(VS.85).aspx) to get managed and native stacks separately and then stitch them together by hand.  Since you're a VS add-in, you might as well let the debugger do the heavy lifting for you!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!  I will definitely give this a try.

Comment: Any chance you know how to get the line numbers and/or function signatures?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out(but it's not pretty) see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14251675/69742

Comment: See http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/get-exception-information-call-stack-7287.aspx. Basically, you can call `DTE.Debugger.GetExpression` to evaluate expressions through the debugger. This might help you get the exception information.

Answer (score -1):

The code is working as expected since when you call the code, your add-in (under VS) is the "current process".

I am not sure what you mean by "currently running process" (do you mean the process being run/debugged under VS?), but I don't think its possible to get a stack-trace of another process.

Comment: Yes I am having the add-in run in Visual Studio while I am debugging a process in the same Visual Studio window and I need access to that process' stack trace inside of my add-in.